# Как реализовать поиск сразу по нескольким полям

Tags: c#, linq, razor

У меня на странице поиска есть 3 поля: name, age, country.
Без кнопки «поиск», фильтрация списка должна происходить сразу по этим 3 полям независимо друг от друга.
Например, если пользователь в поле name введет «Вася», то в списке фильтрация должна быть только по полю name и выведет всех Вась.
А если ввести name=Вася age=18, то фильтровать уже должен по двум полям. Как реализовать такое с помощью linq? Соединять все в большое выражение Where (а если некоторые значения пользователь не введет)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто фильтруйте постепенно:

```
IEnumerable<Human> result = people; // исходные данные

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameFilter)) // nameFilter - фильтр имя
    result = result.Where(human => human.Name.StartsWith(nameFilter));

if (ageFilter is not null) // ageFilter - фильтр возраста
    result = result.Where(human => human.Age == age);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(countryFilter)) // countryFilter - фильтр страны
    result = result.Where(human => human.Country.StartsWith(countryFilter));

// на этом этапе result уже отфильтрован
```